# Port NettworkX graph to Graphviz with edge colors node color, node size

Tags: networkx, graphviz

I tried to draw self loop in NetworkX but not successful so I use GraphViz instead and it works a treat. However, I don't know how I can make the graph nodes and edges into color as I would have in NetworkX.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as cl

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'),('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'C'),('C', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'G'), ('B', 'H'), ('H', 'F')])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
cen = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_color=[cl.to_hex(cm.coolwarm(s)) for s in cen.values()], node_size=[s*1e4 for s in list(cen.values())])
```

[image]

To graphviz

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
write_dot(G,'graph_ex.dot')
```

[image]

How can I get the Graphviz graph to be the same as NetworkX in term of color and node sizes?

Many thanks,

Lucy

Answer (score 0):

dot primary documentation: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf
attribute documentation: https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html
node color (style fillcolor): https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/ & https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fillcolor/
node size: (height, width, and shape):  https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/height/ https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/width/ https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html